# PHP: vcal description is empty

Tags: php, vcalendar

I would really need help with this. I have this function:

```
function sendICal($dtstart,$dtend,$loc,$summary,$from,$to,$subject, $EMAIL, $uid, $decline = 0, $debug = 0) 
{

$now=date('Ymd').'T'.date('His');
$vcal = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$vcal .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$vcal .= "PRODID:ITAF_IMS_NL\r\n";
$vcal .="CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\r\n";

if($debug){

$aan = ',marko.vasic@itaf.eu';
}

 else {

  for($x = 0; $x < count($EMAIL); $x++){
  $aan .= ','.$to[$x];
}
}

if($decline){

  $vcal .="METHOD:REPLY\n";
  $vcal .="BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
  $vcal .="STATUS:CONFIRMED\n";
  for($x = 0; $x < count($EMAIL); $x++){
  $vcal .= "ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=DECLINED;CN=\"\";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=FALSE:MAILTO:".$EMAIL[$x]."\n";

  }

  $vcal .="X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Brussels\n";
  $vcal .="DTSTAMP:".$now."\n";
  $vcal .="DTSTART;TZID:$dtstart\n";
  $vcal .="DTEND:".$dtend."\n";
  $vcal .="SUMMARY:Declined:".$subject."\n";
  $vcal .="SEQUENCE:1\n";
  $vcal .="X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNER-CRITICAL-CHANGE:$now\r\n";
  $vcal .="X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ATTENDEE-CRITICAL-CHANGE:$now\r\n";
  $vcal .="X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:1\n";
  $vcal .="X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-1\n";
  $vcal .="X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE\n";
  $vcal .="END:VEVENT\n";

  } else {

  $vcal .= "METHOD:REQUEST\n";
  $vcal .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
  for($x = 0; $x < count($EMAIL); $x++){
  $vcal .= "ATTENDEE;CN=\"\";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=FALSE:MAILTO:".$EMAIL[$x]."\n";

  }

  $vcal .="CREATED:".$now."\n";
  $vcal .="X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Brussels\n";
  $vcal .="LAST-MODIFIED:".$now."\n";
  $vcal .= "DTSTAMP:".$now."\n";
  $vcal .= "DTSTART:".$dtstart."\n";
  $vcal .= "DTEND:".$dtend."\n";
  $vcal .= "SUMMARY:".$subject."\n";
  $vcal .= "UID:".$uid."\n";
  if ($loc != "") $vcal .= "LOCATION:".$loc."\n";
  $vcal .= "BEGIN:VALARM\n";
  $vcal .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\n";
  $vcal .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\n";
  $vcal .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder:".$summary."\n";
  $vcal .= "END:VALARM\n";
  $vcal .= "END:VEVENT\n";
  } 
 $vcal .= "UID:".$uid."\n";

if ($loc != "") $vcal .= "LOCATION:".$loc."\n";
      $vcal .= "END:VCALENDAR\n";

  $headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from";
  $headers .= "\r\nMIME-version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"";
  $headers .= "\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\nX-Mailer: Microsoft Office     Outlook 12.0";

mail(substr($aan,1), $subject, $vcal, $headers);
 }
```

and it should send event call. It sends everything but description. It always left description field blank. No matter what I send. I strip `<br/>` from string that I send as description and it's still send blank field. Is there some error in headers that I don't see? Does anyone have idea how to fix this?

Comment: Finally found some code that works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the colon `:` after the text "Reminder" - the colon is a special character that delimits the element name and value, you cannot have multiple colons for a single element. You can escape it with a backslash, it should look like this:

```
DESCRIPTION:Reminder\:
```

Multiple lines can be specified in a value by separating them with `CRLF` and a whitespace character immediately afterwards.

Comment: I put this `$vcal .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\:".$summary."\r\n";` and it's still empty. $summary is the description that I want to send.

Comment: What is the content of `$summary`? Is it a multiline text? I.e., does the text contain any newline characters?

Comment: no, I strip all `<br/>`,`<p>` tags from string. I just tried this `$vcal .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";` and it's still empty

Comment: Are you certain you need the `DESCRIPTION` inside the `VALARM`? It may be that it's the event description that is displayed blank and that should be inside `VEVENT` but outside `VALARM`. (The point about escaping the colon `:` character still applies.)

Comment: Just one more question...It send only first word of `$summary` ... anu idea why?

Comment: Does it have any line breaks in that text? I don't mean `<br>` or `<p>` tags but `CR` or `LF` characters? If there are any, the text should be split in lines by using `CRLF` (aka `\r\n`) and a space or tab character immediately after, to indicate that line is a continuation of the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for help! I solve this problem and now I have to solve attendee problem...it won't send invitation to them...

Comment: You're welcome. And the email sending problem is probably a matter for another question - but I encourage you to search first, as that is quite a common problem around here so there are already many questions about sending emails from PHP.

Comment: I found a solution for attadnee problem - now everzthing works fine! Thanks again for help! :D